# Using foreach loop inside a while loop and echo the values

Tags: php, html, arrays, foreach, echo

I have a website where people can upload their videos and if a user uploads a video it makes a new folder called `videos` in their folder e.g. `user/Someone/videos/videoname` and in the `videos` folder there are all the videos that the user uploaded. Then it inserts the video into the database. That works fine, but when I try to echo these videos in an HTML `video` tag I have problems. Since a user can upload more videos I created an `array` called `$url`. Then I select those `videos` that belong to that user (`$sql = "SELECT * FROM videos WHERE user=?";`). Then I push every video item to that `$url` array and I echo the videos with a `foreach` loop. And here is something wrong. There're duplicates, so one video will be echoed more times and there're missing urls.

**Code:**

```
$echo_videos = "";
$items = "";
$url = array();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM videos WHERE user=?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s",$u);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $name = $row["video_file"];
    $items .= "user/$u/videos/$name";
    array_push($url, $items);
    foreach ($url as $key) {
        $echo_videos .= '<video width="400" controls><source src="'.$key.'"></video>';
    }
}
```

PS: Maybe the `$items` variable also should be an array but then I won't be able to push an array to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not you simply echo the filename

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
   echo '<video width="400" controls><source src="user/'.$u.'/videos/'. $row["video_file"].'">
         </video>';
}
```

Comment: Almost good solution, but I'd correct your answer to this: `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo '<video width="400" controls><source src="user/'.$u.'/videos/'. $row["video_file"].'">
          </video>';
 }`

Comment: And I don't know why but the first video does not appear.

Comment: When I comment out that line the `$row["video_file"]` will be equal to nothing.

Comment: i don't understand you last comment  ..  don't tell you of comment the line with  the $row["video_file"]

Comment: You wrote I should comment out line `$result = $stmt->get_result();` but you've already changed that comment and deleted that part... but when I comment out the code will not work.